# How can I handle separate tracks of an AVURLAsset independently?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

Here's my goal: I would like to load a .3gp movie file into an [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset). I would then like to take the video track and pump the output frames into an OpenGL ES texture. This will be the video playback. I would then like to continue leveraging [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation) to play back the audio. The framework is pretty vast, so I'm hoping for some veteran assistance on this one.

I actually have both parts working separately, but something always goes wrong when I try to do both at the same time. Here's my current attempt, in a nutshell (All error handling is omitted for brevity):

I load the .3gp file into the AVURLAsset and load the tracks:

```
NSURL* fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:someName withExtension:someExtension];
AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler:^ {/* More Code */}];
```

In the completion handler, I get a reference to the audio and video track:

```
// Tracks loaded, grab the audio and video tracks.
AVAssetTrack* videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetTrack* audioTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Next, I create separate [AVMutableComposition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablecomposition)s that contain just the audio track and just the video track. I'm not sure if this is completely necessary, but it seems like a good idea and it does also seem to work:

```
// Make a composition with the video track.
AVMutableComposition* videoComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack* videoCompositionTrack = [videoComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[videoCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:[videoTrack timeRange] ofTrack:videoTrack atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:nil];

// Make a composition with the audio track.
AVMutableComposition* audioComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack* audioCompositionTrack = [audioComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[audioCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:[audioTrack timeRange] ofTrack:audioTrack atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:nil];
```

Now I get into specifics of how to handle each track. I'm fairly confident that I have the one-and-only way of handling the video track, which is to create an [AVAssetReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreader) for the video composition, and add an [AVAssetTrackReaderOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreadertrackoutput) that was created with the video composition track. By keeping a reference to that track output, I can call its `-copyNextSampleBuffer` method to get the info I need to pump the video output into an OpenGL ES texture. This works well enough by itself:

```
// Create Asset Reader and Output for the video track.
NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
_assetReader = [[AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:vComposition error:nil] retain];
_videoTrackOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:vCompositionTrack outputSettings:settings] retain];
[_assetReader addOutput:_videoTrackOutput];
[_assetReader startReading];
```

What seems to spoil the whole thing is attempting to play back the audio in any way. I'm not really sure which approach to take for the remaining audio track. Just sticking to the realm of AVFoundation, I see two possible approaches. The first is to use an [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer) to play the audio composition:

```
// Create a player for the audio.
AVPlayerItem* audioPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:aComposition];
AVPlayer* audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:audioPlayerItem] retain];
[audioPlayer play];
```

This works, inasmuch as I can hear the desired audio. Unfortunately creating this player guarantees that the AVAssetReaderTrackOutput for the video composition fails with a cryptic error when calling `-copyNextSampleBuffer`:

> AVAssetReaderStatusFailed
>
> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain
>   Code=-11800 "The operation could not
>   be completed" UserInfo=0x456e50
>   {NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown
>   error occurred (-12785),
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x486570 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (OSStatus error -12785.)",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation
>   could not be completed}

I'm confused about how they might be interfering with each other, but regardless, that approach seems to be a dead end.

The other option I considered for the audio playback was the [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) class, but I could not get it to work with an AVAsset as a starting point. I attempted to use its `-initWithData:error:` method with an NSData built by aggregating the contents of CMSampleBufferRefs taken with an approach identical to the one I use on the video track, but it does not appear to be formatted correctly.

At this point, I feel like I'm flailing around blindly, and would love it so very much if someone could tell me if this approach is even feasible. If it's not I would, of course, appreciate a feasible one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating AVMutableCompositions (basically new AVAssets) for each track seems round-about to me, I'd simply use an AVAssetReader on the audio track. Also, your videoComposition doesn't seem to be used anywhere, so why create it?

In any case, to get either solution to work, set your audio session category to `kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback` and enable `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers`.

I've never found any documentation that explains why this is necessary.

Comment: I omitted the code that uses the video composition because it works and would just increase the size of an already lengthy question. Anyways, setting those properties on the audio session nailed the problem. Thanks for saving me hours of frustration. I had never even heard of AVAudioSession...